# remove all class on tag with jquery and add new

Tags: jquery, html, css

how can I remove active class from current a tag and set active class to another , where we clicked? I try to make it this way , but it doesn't work :)

```js
$(function() {
  $(".bir").click(function() {
    // remove classes from all
    $("a").removeClass("active");
    // add class to the one we clicked
    $(".bir").addClass("active");

  });
});
```

```css
a {
  color: #2a6496;
}
a.janduu {
  color: #d11250;
}
```

```html
<a href="form.php?lang=kr" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="кыргызча" class="janduu bir">КЫР</a>
<span>|</span>
<a href="form.php?lang=tr" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="türkçe" class="bir">TUR</a>
<span>|</span>
<a href="form.php?lang=en" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="english" class="bir">ENG</a>
<span>|</span>
<a href="form.php?lang=ru" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="русский" class="bir">РУС</a>
```

Comment: To remove use `$("a.active").removeClass("active");` and to add it on the clicked element use `$(this)`. `$(this).addClass('active');`

Comment: Seems like after clicking the link, the page will get a refresh. After page refresh browser will reset the dynamically added class `active`. In this scenario. backend language will help you.

Comment: Tushar you propose to use double  $(this)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $(".bir").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // remove classes from all
        if(!$(this).hasClass("janduu")){
            $(this).addClass("janduu");
            $(this).siblings().removeClass("janduu");
        }
        // add class to the one we clicked


    });
});
```

try this way

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q5w3w9fL/)

Comment: Dear Pekka , your solution is perfect , unfortunately after using your solution my links doesn't work.

Comment: @ГаухарТаалайкызы remove the `e.preventDefault();` i put it there for testing purposes. It is will make the link not work.

Comment: I have already made it , but problem is , that when I click the link and  page is loaded ,  the color of <a> tag wich situated on the current page  changed only on click .

Comment: are you loading the link in same page?and when you do back to the page it returns to previous setting is that what you mean?\

Comment: when I click , it just load some php files and my page  language changed.